# Simultaneous equation with fractions

Tags: systems-of-equations

> Given the system of equations 
>   $$
> \frac{2}{x} + \frac{3}{y} = 6  \quad \text{and}\quad
> 5x - y = 4  
> $$
>   solve for $x$ and $y$.

I have tried rearranging the equation to substitute either $x$ or $y$, but I wasn't able to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=5x-4$ in the first equation and multiply the equation by $x(5x-4)$ You will get  quadratic equation in $x$. Do you know how to solve  a quadratic equation?

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $y$ by $5x-4$ in the first equation, you get$$\frac2x+\frac3{5x-4}=6.\tag1$$But\begin{align}(1)&\iff\frac2x+\frac3{5x-4}-6=0\\&\iff\frac{-30 x^2+31 x-8}{x (5 x-4)}=0.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: just a question, how did you go from (1) to (2) where you have everything over one denominator?

Comment: I had several fractions and then I summed them into a single fraction.